# how to align text with Icon in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, text

I'm trying to align my text with the icon next to it but some reason it doesn't work. I put margin-bottom and margin-top but still not working so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
    <div class="notification"
        [ngClass]="{'noty-error' : (caraouselItems[notificationIndex].notificationType==1),'noty-warn': (caraouselItems[notificationIndex].notificationType==2)}"
        *ngIf="caraouselItems[notificationIndex].message">
        <div class="firstPart">
            <i-feather name="x-circle" *ngIf="caraouselItems[notificationIndex].notificationType==1" class="noty-error-icon"></i-feather>
            <i-feather name="alert-triangle" *ngIf="caraouselItems[notificationIndex].notificationType==2" class="noty-warn-icon"></i-feather>
            <span>
                {{caraouselItems[notificationIndex].message}}
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```
  .notification {
    padding: 0px 14px  ;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}

.noty-error {
    background-color:#32111C;
    border: 1px solid #D2232B;
}

.noty-error-icon {
    color: #D2232B;
    margin-right: 14px;
    stroke-width: 1 !important;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add `flexbox ` in `firstPart` div

Comment: what should I add?

Comment: .firstPart {display: flex;align-items: center;}

Answer (score 0):

```
  Just put this style and adjust according to your position for alignment
    whatever you need bottom it will work hopefully

 

 <span style="position:relative;bottom:2px;">
                {{caraouselItems[notificationIndex].message}}
            </span>
```